# How to get random Core Data element from ForEach in Widget

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm working on a widget in iOS 14 that will show images from Core Data as submitted by my users. Currently, I can show a single image, but it's not rotating through the Project images.. it's only showing a single image in the widget.

In my Widget.swift, the only way I can get an image to show is by using a ForEach. If I don't use the ForEach, I get the error `Value of type 'FetchedResults<Project>' has no member 'image1'`

Here's the (mostly) working code

```
struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @State var projectImage1: Data = .init(count: 0)
    @FetchRequest(entity: Project.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var project: FetchedResults<Project>
    
    var body: some View {
    
            ForEach((project.prefix(1)), id: \.self) { (project: Project) in
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: project.image1 ?? self.projectImage1) ?? UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "icon"))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            }.environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)
    }
}
```

Again, if I use the below code, I get the **no member** error for some reason

```
struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @State var projectImage1: Data = .init(count: 0)
    @FetchRequest(entity: Project.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var project: FetchedResults<Project>
    
    var body: some View {
        
       Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: project.image1 ?? self.projectImage1) ?? UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "icon"))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }.environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)
    }
}
```

How can I have the ForEeach show a random `project.image1` attribute? I've tried appending `randomElement()` and `shuffle()` but neither are accepted.

Here's the full Widget.swift: https://pastebin.com/aFMuZ0iz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FetchedResults<Project>` is a collection data type, so it won't have an `image1` property like an element in the collection of type `Project`.  You're using the `prefix(1)` method which is returning a sub-collection with one element...but it's still a collection.

Try something like this:

```
if let randomProject: Project = project.randomElement()
{
   Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: randomProject.image1 ?? self.projectImage1))
}
else
{
   Image(uiImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "icon"))
}
```

`project.randomElement()` will return a random element from the collection if not empty, else nil.

Comment: Had to keep the Image(uiImage:) for data conversion, but this works beautifully, thank you @CSmith!

Comment: oops my bad on the Image() syntax, I edited the answer.  Glad to help